# Python PIL how to paste an image in all black square

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

The goal is to paste a transparent PNG file on a base image that is 1000 x 1000. My code so far pastes an image that is 250 x 250 on to the base image but is randomly placed throughout the base image. The outcome looks like this [image]

Here is a a peice of the code so you guys can see what is going on.

```
import random
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageOps, ImageFont 

###This creates the base image ###
base = Image.new('RGB',(1000,1000),'black')
base.save('base_image.jpg')

### Opens up all the images that will be used###
jon = Image.open('jon_snow.jpg')
rejon = Image.open('resized_jon.jpg')
wolf = Image.open('wolf.png')


### The List of locations around the base image ###
location = [(0,0),(0,250),(0,500),(0,750),(250,0),(250,250),(250,500),(250,750),(500,0),(500,250),(500,500),(500,750),(750,0),(750,250),(750,500),(750,750),(0,0),(0,250),(0,500),(0,750),(250,0),(250,250),(250,500),(250,750),(500,0),(500,250),(500,500),(500,750),(750,0),(750,250),(750,500),(750,750)]
### Opertaions used ###
def image_resize(image,size):
  image.resize((size))
  image.save('resized_jon.jpg')
  return


def image_invert(image):
  inverted = ImageOps.invert(image)
  base.paste(inverted,random.choice(location))
  base.save('base_image.jpg')
  return

def fill_base():
  for x in range(6):
    image_invert(rejon)
```

I didnt add all the operations just to save time. So as you can see when the random is used it doesnt fill up all the black squares all the time it is generated. So that is whne i want to create a for loop maybe or something to check when those squares are black so then i can paste a PNG file there at that location. Is it possible to check for those black squares? Any help

Comment: I suspect what you're asking for is "I want to use each value in `location` exactly once, but in a random order". If this is what you want, I recommend `random.shuffle`.

Comment: well not exactly. In the blank spots as seen in the image. i want to paste another image. only if that spot is blank or in this case all black @Kevin

Comment: I'm making a small logical leap here between "how do I make sure that there aren't any gaps in the collection I'm randomly sampling from?" and "how do I make sure I select _every_ element in my collection eventually?". The two problems are only equivalent if the regions in the collection do not overlap, and if you are taking exactly `len(location)` samples. I haven't verified that either of these are true.

Comment: I'm not so sure what you mean. To dumb things down. All i need help with is a for loop that checks if all the pixels are black in that location. And if that's true i can paste that image there @Kevin

Comment: I will rephrase. You don't need to detect black rectangles in your output image if the 16 images you're pasting onto it are each placed in a unique position. Black rectangles only appear if you randomly select the same position more than once. Iterating over a shuffled list is an effective way of randomizing data while ensuring all values are used.

Comment: Got it! I understand that now. In my case i want to have those black rectangles. I want them So i can paste another image there. Thus why i need something to help determine where they are

Comment: How many images do you have to go in the 16 squares?

Comment: What about simply saving your `random.choice()` results in another variable (or delete them from `location`)? The difference to `location` (or what is left) are the positions of your black squares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can track the results of `random.choice` so that you already know which squares are left blank(/black), for example by using the return value of your tile pasting function:

```
def image_invert(image):
    inverted = ImageOps.invert(image)
    r = random.choice(location)
    base.paste(inverted, r)
    base.save('base_image.jpg')
    return r
```

*(Note: you don't need a `return` statement if your function has no return value)*

---

Mcve of shrinking `location` with every pasted tile:

```
import random
from PIL import Image

###This creates the base image ###
base = Image.new('RGB',(1000,1000),'black')
location = [(250*a, 250*b) for a in range(4) for b in range(4)]

jon = Image.new('RGB', (250, 250), 'red')

print('locations used:')
for i in range(10):
    r = random.choice(location)
    location.pop(location.index(r))
    base.paste(jon, r)
    print(r)

base.save('base_image.jpg')
print('\nlocations left black:')
print(location)
```

Result:

```
# locations used:
# (500, 250)                                              
# (0, 750)                                                   
# (250, 0)                                                   
# (750, 500)                                                  
# (0, 500)                                                    
# (250, 500)                                                 
# (750, 0)                                                    
# (750, 750)                                                  
# (0, 250)                                                   
# (500, 500)                                

# locations left black:                                      
# [(0, 0), (250, 250), (250, 750), (500, 0), (500, 750), (750, 250)]
```

Comment: Nice answer, and you have my vote. Quick question though from a Python beginner, when you created the list called `location`, why did you put it in parentheses? I mean why do `location = ([...])` rather than `location = [...]` ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to *test* a tile of your image against being completely black, you can cast the image to a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
B = np.array(base)
(B[0:250, 0:250]==0).all()
# True or False
```

You can use this test for a list of all black tiles with

```
blk_loc = [l for l in location if (B[l[1]:l[1]+250, l[0]:l[0]+250]==0).all()]
```

*(Note that you have to swap the order of x and y for numpy's row and column indices.)*